# Having difficulty accessing the .contentDocument of an svg when running Cypress

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, svg, cypress

If I run my app in the browser normally (Chrome), everything is fine, but if I try in Chrome with a Cypress test (just a basic one that opens the app in localhost:3000 and so far does nothing else), I get the following error during the page load:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')
    at ui.js:203:19
    at i ((index):4:1616)
    at (index):4:1989
```

Upon further investigation, the function that causes the problem is the one that sets up the svg file and returns a variable set to true, that is periodically checked to resolve a promise elsewhere in the app to signify the app is ready.  So, if I put a breakpoint on the line in my app that sets the value of `svgMap`, I can see when I step over it in the Cypress run, that it returns `null`, but in the normal browser run without Cypress it returns the document of the `#svg-map` element perfectly well:

```
export function svgMapLoaded() {
  //-------------GLOBAL SVG CONSTANTS AFTER SVG LOADED---------------//
  svg = document.getElementById('svg-map');
  svgMap = document.getElementById('svg-map').contentDocument; // <-- this line returns null in Cypress
  svgTag = svgMap.querySelector('svg');
  paths = Array.from(svgMap.querySelectorAll('path'));
//rest of function
```

Incidentally, the `#svg-map` element is an `object` element:
`<object id="svg-map" data="resources/svgMaster.svg" type="image/svg+xml" tabindex="0"></object>`

This function is called as follows on page load:

```
<head>
    <script type="module" src="initialData.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="resources/SVGPathData.cjs"></script> -->
    <script type="module" src="transferAndAttack.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="resourceCalculations.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="gameTurnsLoop.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
    import {
        svgMapLoaded
    } from "./ui.js";
    const svg = document.getElementById("svg-map");
    svg.addEventListener("load", () => {
        svgMapLoaded();
    });
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="ui.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="music.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="manualExceptionsForInteractions.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Domination: World Conquest</title>
</head>
```

Obviously this variable returning null means that the rest of the function fails, and therefore the cypress test.  **Please can someone inform me of any special ways to configure Cypress to work correctly? I will gladly provide any further information.**

I tried adding a timeout of one second to the function in my app to see if that might help, but it seems like it has already been doomed to failure before the timeout is executed, as stepping over the line still returns `null`.

Comment: It looks like a the way you are serving the page may be the problem. If I add your `<object>` to an html page, Cypress loads it and associated `<svg>` without problem. Take a look at devtools network tab to see if the page is getting `svgMaster.svg`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting a 200 on the file and in the response i see what is expected, as in the non truncated version of the below:

<?xml
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="312 -207 1947 1040" style="shape-rendering: geometricprecision;" stroke-width="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image width="3000" height="2000" y="-700" xlink:href="<theImage>"/>
    <rect x="200" y="-207" width="2170" height="1040" opacity="0"/>
    <path  d="M 1213.083 75.581 L 1213.083 75.581 Z" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/>
etc